# Настройка шрифта в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Подскажите пожалуйста, как "утолстить" шрифт в IntelliJ IDEА? Просто в Windows он настолько тонок, что смотреть неприятно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете также попробовать программу [MacType](https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype), которая использует другой алгоритм растеризации шрифтов в Windows. Они станут выглядеть немного потолще.

Comment: Как настроить шрифт Zapfino Extra Pro Regular в Intellij IDEA? ![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgPIj.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

File -> Settings .. -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снять флажок с *Show only Monospaced Fonts* и выбрать подходящий из Bold

или

File -> Settings .. -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> General: Text -> Default Text

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

отметить флажок Bold

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли! Недавно начал изучать java и еще многого не знаю, в том числе и как более удобно "под себя" настроить свою среду разработки.

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите в `File -> Settings .. -> Editor -> Font` и в `Size` измените размер